# can't intialize Async task in main, and can't get a response to my http request

Tags: c#

I am trying to post an http request and get the response, but I have two problmes. first I don't know how to intialize the async task in the main class. and I can't figure out how to get the response to my http request. please see my code below :)

```
enter code here
internal static class Program
{
    private static IStorageClient Client;
    private static IClientOptions ClientOptions;

    [STAThread]
    public static void Main()
    {
        Main();
        Task.Run(() => (Client, ClientOptions));
        //Upload();
        static async Task<string> GetData(string url, string data)
        {
            
                var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, url);
                request.RequestUri = new Uri("https://api.backblazeb2.com/b2api/v2/b2_authorize_account");
                String applicationKeyId = "app_id";
                String applicationKey = "key_id";
                String credentials = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(applicationKeyId + ":" + applicationKey));
                string eHeaders = "Authorization" + "Basic " + credentials;
                request.Headers.Add(eHeaders, string.Empty);
                request.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application / json; charset = utf - 8");
            
                string responsestring = null;
                return responsestring = "Done!";
                MessageBox.Show(data);
            
        }
```

Comment: From your code I see no invocation of the GetData method. You are also calling Main recursively

Comment: Any reason you don't want to just write an async main method?

Answer (score 0):

Just your code with a few fixes, implementation logic has not been checked:

```
internal static class Program
{
    private static IStorageClient Client;
    private static IClientOptions ClientOptions;

    public static async Task Main()
    {
        var data = await GetData (Client, ClientOptions);
        MessageBox.Show(data);

        //Upload();

        static async Task<string> GetData(string url, string data)
        {
        
            var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, url);
            request.RequestUri = new Uri("https://api.backblazeb2.com/b2api/v2/b2_authorize_account");
            String applicationKeyId = "app_id";
            String applicationKey = "key_id";
            String credentials = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(applicationKeyId + ":" + applicationKey));
            string eHeaders = "Authorization" + "Basic " + credentials;
            request.Headers.Add(eHeaders, string.Empty);
            request.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application / json; charset = utf - 8");
        
            string responsestring = null;
            return responsestring = "Done!";
        
        }
    }
}
```